# Why in_array() is not returning me as true

Tags: php

I have a MySQLI result set:

```
$prems = $mysqli->query($query);
$noofupid = mysqli_num_rows($prems);
```

I know that one row is found with values as 'CIR'. Next I fetch that value as:

```
$perm = $prems->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
```

Now I need to check if either 'C' or 'I' or 'R' value is set in the array:

```
if($noofupid > 0)
    echo in_array("C", $perm);
```

But the if is failing.

Actually my exact condition is:

```
if( $noofupid > 0 && in_array('C', $perm))
    echo '<option value="C" selected>Create</option>';
else
    echo '<option value="C">Create</option>';
```

Always the else part gets executed. Any idea why the above is not yielding correct results?

**===EDIT====**

```
echo var_dump($perm) ;
echo var_dump($noofupid);
```

Values:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'CIR' (length=3)
  'property_value' => string 'CIR' (length=3)

int 1

null

int 0

null

int 0

null

int 0

null

int 0

null

int 0

null

int 0

null

int 0

null

int 0
```

Comment: What does var_dump($noofupid) and var_dump($perm) show?

Comment: Are you sure your database requests are working? You're not doing any error checking.

Comment: Yes I have manually verified by echoing output and verifying the query in Phpadmin

Comment: @Prakash "I know that one row is found" who told you? It doesn't matter what PHPmyadmin says, your might be querying it completely wrong on the PHP side, not SQL (although you can't be sure) wise but simply the mysqli part. -- And even if you're actually getting something it doesn't mean it's on the format you think it is. Follow the best practices (catch errors, log, and actually check the errors and the logs), and you'll rarely need to ask a question.

Comment: Can we see the output so we can help? Or at least the part of the output that will help.

Comment: So, one column in your database holds a string "CRI"? Then you're looking for `strpos`, not `in_array`, because you need to work on a string, not an array. Otherwise, clarify what exactly is in `$perm`.

Comment: `know that one row is found with values as 'CIR'` - i.e. one of the fields in a row contains the _string_ `CIR`? `in_array()` compares whole elements not sub-parts of them.

Comment: Btw, I hope you're not making it a habit of naming highly related variables  almost the same, e.g. `$prems` and `$perm`.

Comment: I have echoed the $query and $noofupid values I am sure that query resulted one row. The query is programmatically created - "select property_value from permissions where userid=" . $user['userid'] . " and property_id=" . $priv['property_id'] . " LIMIT 1";

Comment: so what is inside $perm!!! `var_dump($perm);`

Comment: I have updated the question with details as requested

Comment: Thanks, by the way, FYI, you don't need to `echo` it. `var_dump` outputs itself.

Comment: Ok, now we can see the array, we can do a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a string. So you need to split the string to use in_array.

```
if( $noofupid > 0 && in_array('C', preg_split('//',$perm[0])))
```

or find the character in the string

```
if( $noofupid > 0 && false !== strstr($perm[0], 'C'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use in_array() for strings, you have to convert the string to array first:

```
$array = str_split("CIR");
```

You will get this array:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "C"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "I"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "R"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Dear you are getting associative value in $perm variable, so you can't match directly array value by in_array function.

You can match array key in your case.
example: in_array("$keyofPermVariable",$perm)

otherwise can do it by using one function more like

```
$perm_result = array_flip($perm);
if($noofupid > 0 && in_array("C", $perm_result))
    echo '<option value="C" selected>Create</option>';
else
    echo '<option value="C">Create</option>';
```

array_flip will change key to value and vice-versa.